# Set date limit in DatePickerDialog android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using DatePickerDialog in my activity ,

I want to set limit the date DatePickerDialog by user.

They should not able to select date more than current date.

My DatePickerDialog  java code

```
edittodate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            edittodate.setText("");

             final Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
               int mYear=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               int mMonth=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               int mDay=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
               final Date curDate= new Date();
                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(ViewChallan.this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                        /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        if(mcurrentDate.before(curDate))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            selectedmonth= selectedmonth+1;
                            edittodate.setText(selectedyear+"-"+selectedmonth+"-"+selectedday);
                        }


                    }
                },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date"); 
             // this code below is not hiding calendar,stopping the application
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
                }
                mDatePicker.show(); 

        }
        });
```

Please Suggest me how can set limit in date

Thanks In Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18353944/2274724

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `setMinDate(long)` and `setMaxDate(long)` methods at your disposal. Both of these will work on API level 11 and above. Since you are using a `DatePickerDialog`, you need to first get the underlying `DatePicker` by calling the `getDatePicker()` method.

```
dpdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);  
dpdialog.getDatePicker().setmaxDate(maxDate);
```

Source: [Set Limit on the DatePickerDialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android/18353944#18353944)

**Edit:**

```
Date today = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(today);
c.add( Calendar.MONTH, -6 ) // Subtract 6 months
long minDate = c.getTime().getTime() // Twice!
```

Source: [java.util.Date - Deleting three months from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311143/java-util-date-deleting-three-months-from-a-date)

Comment: working fine but how define  Min date(min date is before 6 month of the current date)

Comment: See the edit. Please do consider accepting answers if you want to get answers to your future questions on SO.

Comment: Instead calling getTime twice could you use getTimeInMillis instead?

Comment: Ah yes... that too. I forgot (:

Answer (score 0):

Setting minumum and maximum date for the DatePickerDialog is not enough. User can click on the year and select any other year.

You should also set year range on the DatePicker like this:

```
datePicker.setYearRange(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
```